# SymmetricDS in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, symmetricds

I am interested in using SymmetricDS in a Spring Boot application. Are there any examples that demonstrate how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS is a Spring application itself so it shouldn't be such a big deal integrating it with Spring Boot. There are yet no examples of it. You can always run it in standalone mode.